# How to passing c# function as a param to UnityScript in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a class using UnityScript like this:

```
public class Responder{
    private var completeHandler:Function;

    public function addHandlers(completeHandler:Function):void {
        completeHandler();
    }
}
```

Now, i want to use this class in c# code,

```
public class MyGame : MonoBehaviour{
    void Start(){
        Responder res = new Responder();
        res.addHandlers(?????);   //how to pass the param??
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put the Javascript class in a folder called `Plugins` under assets. You will be able to call the methods written in JS from C# scripts.

The type `Function` in JS appears to me as `Boo.Lang.ICallable` in C#. As I couldn't import Boo.Lang by default, I took the `Boo.Lang.dll` from the Unity3D installed folder and copied it to the same `Plugins` folder in the project, then adding `using Boo.Lang;` at the top of my C# script.

You can now create and pass a new `ICallable` type as an argument from C# to JS.